# How to pass ref const from parent to child component in react functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I am working on the Reactjs project and I want to open a dialog box which is a global component from a cart page.
This is cart page when I click on cart delete button then it shows dialog current is null.

```
/**
 * Cart Page
 */
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Button,Box} from '@material-ui/core';
import { ConfirmationDialog } from 'components/GlobalComponents';
import IntlMessages from 'util/IntlMessages';

function Cart(props){
    const [anchorEl,setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    const [item,setItem] = React.useState('');
    const dialog = React.useRef(null);

    const onDeleteCartItem = (item) => {
        // setItem(item);
        console.log(dialog);
        // dialog.current.open();
    }

    const deleteCartItem = (popupResponse) => {
        console.log(popupResponse);
   }
   
    return (
        <div className="cart-page white-btn-color">
            <Button
                className="cart-delete"
                onClick={() => onDeleteCartItem(cart)}
            >
                <Box component="span" className="material-icons-outlined">delete</Box>
            </Button>                       
            <ConfirmationDialog
                ref={dialog}
                onConfirm={(res) => deleteCartItem(res)}
            />                          
        </div>
    )
}

export default Cart;
```

Confirmation Dialog:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dialog, DialogContent, DialogActions, Button, Box, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

function ConfirmationDialog(props) {
   const [open,setOpen] = React.useState(false);
   


   //Define function for open confirmation dialog box
   const openDialog = () => {
      setOpen(true);
   };

   //Define function for close confirmation dialog box and callback for delete item 
   const closeDialog = (isTrue) => {
      setOpen(false);
      props.onConfirm(isTrue)
   };
   console.log(props);
   return (
      <Dialog
         open={open}
         ref={props.ref}
         onClose={()=>closeDialog()}
         aria-labelledby="responsive-dialog-title"
      >
         <DialogContent>
                <Box textAlign="center" pt={2}>
                    <Typography variant="h5">
                        Are you sure you want to delete this product ?
                    </Typography>
                </Box>
         </DialogContent>
      </Dialog >
   );
}

export { ConfirmationDialog };
```

I am trying with the above-mentioned code this is not working please tell me where I`m wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going wrong. Firstly, the `ref` prop has a special meaning and is not passed to the component unless you use `React.forwardRef()`.

Then, according to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs) you should not use ref as a means to expose an API, so to speak.

My preferred method is to define the dialog way up in the component tree and expose the open/close functions via a context. You can consume those methods with `useContext()` or even create your own `useDialog()` which internally calls `useContext()` (in the file that declares the dialog) with the local context object, so you don't have to export the context object.